# Does ParentClass.NestedClass nc= new NestedClass(); implicitly instantiate parent class instance?

Tags: java, nested, inner-classes

I have a code from textbook:

```
public class Question_3_4 {
  public static class Inner {
    private void doIt() {
      System.out.println("doIt()");
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Question_3_4.Inner i = new Inner();
    i.doIt();
  }
}
```

Well, Inner class is static, so I assume the above code implicitly instantiates Question_3_4's instance ?

```
Question_3_4.Inner i = new Question_3_4.Inner();
```

produces the same result as above code.

So I assume

```
  Question_3_4.Inner i = new Question_3_4.Inner();
```

and

```
  Question_3_4.Inner i = new Inner();
```

are the same thing.

If my assumption is wrong what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't use the correct terminology.

You didn't declare a inner class but a static nested class.

> Terminology: **Nested classes are divided into two categories**: static
>   and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are called
>   **static nested classes**. Non-static nested classes are called **inner
>   classes**.

You could get accessible and useful information about terminology and how and why use nested classes on the [Java Oracle Nested Classes tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) :

About your question :

> Well, Inner class is static, so I assume the above code implicitly
>   instantiates Question_3_4's instance ?

You don't need to instantiate the outer class to instantiate a nested class or says also a `static` nested class.
Besides, the compiler will not instantiate the outer class for you if it was required but would emit a compilation error.

Instantiating the outer class is required only in case of inner classes (no `static` nested class).

For example remove the `static` modifier of the nested class and a compilation error will be produced for the  `Question_3_4.Inner i = new Inner();` line as it requires to have an instance of the outer class to be instantiated.

```
public class Question_3_4 {

     public class Inner {
             private void doIt() {
                     System.out.println("doIt()");
             }
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
             Question_3_4.Inner i = new Inner(); 
             ^--- error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context              
             i.doIt();
     }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much davidxxx . I am a bit lost now, because static, in general, means that it is not tied to one particular instance and is accessible to all instances ( like a static variable and methods are reachable by all instances of a class). So what does it mean "instantiating a static inner class" ? In this case (if it is an instance) it would not be reachable by all instance members directly and only by using the instance variable ( right? is it reachable only by instance variable? ). I mean isn't it a case where meaning of static is lost ?

Comment: "instantiating a static inner class"  does't mean anything. Either a nested class is `static` or it is `inner`. Not both. Then : "because static, in general, means that it is not tied to one particular instance and is accessible to all instances" Yes but not only. More generally, a `static` member means a member that is not related to an instance. So any instance may refer to a `static` member but **you don't need an instance to refer it either**.

Comment: Try to read carefully my answer and deepen it with this tutorials : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html and  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html  and  you will get it without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

no in that case (since inner is static, you dont need an instance of the partent class in order to create an inner instance)... is not instantiating the parent class...

you can verify that by writing a constructor of the parent class and checking how that is never invoked...

```
public class Calculator {
    public Calculator() {
        System.out.println("Hello Constructor Calc");
    }

    public static class Inner {
        private void doIt() {
            System.out.println("doIt()");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator.Inner i = new Inner();
        i.doIt();
        Calculator.Inner i2 = new Calculator.Inner();
        i2.doIt();
    }
}
```

both instances i and i2 will produce only

> doIt()
>
> doIt()

Comment: Thank you very much ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ .

I am a bit lost now, because static, in general, means that it is not tied to one particular instance and is accessible to all instances ( like a static variable and methods are reachable by all instances of a class). 

So what does it mean "instantiating a static inner class" ?   In this case (if it is an instance) it would not be reachable by all instance members directly and only by using the instance variable ( right? is it reachable only by instance variable? ). 

I mean isn't it a case where meaning of static is lost ?

Answer (score 1):

No. You don't need outer class reference to access static inner class.

Static nested class is just like any another top level class and just grouped to maintain the relation. It is not at all a member of outer class. You can access it directly.

> Note: A [static nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.) interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.

However in non static inner class, what you said is correct.

> A [nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.) is a member of its enclosing class. Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private. Static nested classes do not have access to other members of the enclosing class.

To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this syntax:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

Comment: Thank you very much @SURESHATTA. 

I am a bit lost now, because static, in general, means that it is not tied to one particular instance and is accessible to all instances ( like a static variable and methods are reachable by all instances of a class). 

So what does it mean "instantiating a static inner class" ?   In this case (if it is an instance) it would not be reachable by all instance members directly and only by using the instance variable ( right? is it reachable only by instance variable? ). 

I mean isn't it a case where meaning of static is lost ?

Comment: Yes, general meaning of static won't apply here. Just make things clearer, you can assume that in this case of static class, general static rules won't apply